# How do I return a list of columns from a Pandas DataFrame, via conditional selection, where all the values in a row are True?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, selection

I have the following Pandas DataFrame as an example.  This specific dataFrame has already been returned as a conditionally selected subset of a larger dataframe, such that there will be only one row with a datetime index.

```
            Apple   Banana  Lemon   Orange  Pear
2018-04-05  True    False   False   True    True
```

I want to return a list of the columns where the column value is True.

So here, I want to return a list that contains Apple, Orange and Pear.

I have the following solution that works:

```
afruitlist = []
for column in df.columns:
    if df[column][0] == True:
        afruitlist.append(column)
    else:
        pass
afruitlist
```

However, is there a way to do this by deploying conditional selection to the dataframe without having to deploy the loop explicitly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given that your result is only one row, you can index using df.any()

```
df.loc[:, df.any()].columns.tolist()

['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC sine the dataframe is bool datatype, we can using `np.where`

```
[x for x in np.where(df,df.columns,'').tolist()[0] if x]
Out[162]: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']
```